# Using HM-10 module vs CC2540/1

Tags: embedded, uart, bluetooth-low-energy, at-commands, iot

Currently I'm trying to buy a BLE module, and the [HM-10 module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WGZB2N4) seems to be a module built around the [CC2540](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2540#design-development) or [CC2541](https://www.ti.com/product/CC2541#product-details) chips.

The HM-10 module is a module that works whit UART and AT-commands, I want to buy some chips to build a custom board, the thing is that we can't put the HM-10 modules into the final custom board, we should put the CC2540/1, but what exactly does this mean?

When reading the datasheet I found out that these are system-on-chip, does this mean that we should program all the AT-Command protocol and all the BLE protocol from scratch into the CC2540/1 first?

Comment: Yes, but TI provides the bluetooth software stack and demo code.